# Passing parameters in cucumber steps

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to pass one parameter in cucumber step but the method have two
This is my code

```
 @Given("^skip the next scenario named \"(.*)\"$")
@BeforeStep
public void before(Scenario scenario, String name) {
    if (scenario.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {

        Assume.assumeTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Is there any idea to pass only the name ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to skip a scenario based on the name

Comment: And which test framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using selenium, java, Junit runner and cucumber

Answer (score 0):

[Cucumber-JUnit](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit) allows you to filter scenarios based on `tags` and `name`.

The `name` takes a regex. So given a feature with two scenarios where we want to skip the `Addition` scenario:

```
Feature: Basic Arithmetic

  Background: A Calculator
    Given a calculator I just turned on

  Scenario: Addition
    When I add 4 and 5
    Then the result is 9

  Scenario: Another Addition
    When I add 4 and 7
    Then the result is 11
```

We have to write a regex that excludes `Addition` but includes `Another Addition`. One way to do this is to use a negative look-ahead regex:

```java
package io.cucumber.examples.calculator;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(name = "^(?!Addition).*$")
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```